# Run command on client computer from a browser

Tags: browser, command, client-side

I was wondering if it was possible, using some client side scripting language, to run a command on a client computer from a remote web server. For example, what could I do to make a web page that returns information about the client's local ip address, currently running processes, and other info by running some command on their machine and then collecting and printing that data? Also, I only intend to use this on clients running Windows. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

The amount of information you can collect from client computers is deliberately limited in the name of privacy. If you wanted to accomplish your goals, you would have to have the user consent to giving you this information. For example, you could ask them to install and run a small program on their machine, not limited by what the browser can do or see, and use that to collect and return information to you. The act of asking them to run this program/install a plugin would be the consent. For example, this is what NVidia does to scan your computer and determine which drivers you need on their website, as seen here: http://www.nvidia.com/Download/Scan.aspx?lang=en-us

Answer (score 0):

I think Pwn2Own is over for this year.  Even with that, I would hope not.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's called hacking.  Browser makers go to great length to prevent this kind of activity because it poses a massive security risk to your users.  There might be a way to do such a thing, but it's WRONG to try it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! My intention is not malicious. In fact, it's quite the opposite. What I'm trying to do is collect information about the processes running on a client machine from the browser and then run those through a database of known malicious processes in order to help the client find potentially harmful software on their computers. To do this, I need to run commands on their computer from a web server. Sorry if it sounded hackerish :)

Comment: Building something like an Active-x control for IE then is your only option, or making a down-loadable program that talks to your server.  Anything you do with normal browser code will be a hack or exploit.